# How to call an label in a section while I defined it in another section in NASM?

Tags: assembly, nasm

```
section dseg
bits 16
gdt:
code_descriptor:     
.......

section cseg
bits 16
start:
    mov ax, seg dseg
```

When I compile this file, it says:

> error : symbol 'dseg' undefined.

What is wrong? And how to call the offset address of cseg?

Comment: can't you simply jump to the offset of dseg?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
bits 16

section dseg
; ...

section cseg
start:
    mov ax, dseg
; ...
```

Comment: Thank you all the same, but it says " symbol 'dseg' undefined" again.

Comment: How do you assemble the code? What is the exact command? What output format are you using?

Comment: And how do you think segments will work with a format not supporting segments??? `-f obj` will work.